# Pop a page from stack in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I have pages that is accessible in two different tabs in Ionic 4. The problem is when I changed tabs without popping the details screen, whenever I try to access it again from another tab, the previous info is still shown.

I have already tried using **navigateRoot** but it doesn't pop the previous pages. It keeps the pages alive that prevents the code in the constructor from being executed.

The entire flow goes like this:
On tab 1, I accessed a list screen. When I selected an item in the list, its details is shown in another page. Then I go to tab 2 without popping the details screen. From tab 2, I accessed the same list screen. But this time I selected a different item from the list. But it shows the details of the item I selected from tab 1.

Is there anyone that can help me with this? Any ideas or suggestions will do.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the code you use to populate the tab in the first place is in the wrong method.

The constructor /ngInit is only called once.

If you want to setup the page again each time the user revisits the page then you can use the `ionViewWillEnter`.

More information about the page lifecycle:

- [Ionic Page Life Cycle - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)